# What does ドン引き mean?

Tags: words, meaning

While i was talking with my japanese friends, that word just came up they could't explain that. Can you tell me what does ドン引き mean?

Comment: Can you read Japanese well? This was the very first google result for ドン引き http://zokugo-dict.com/20to/donbiki.htm

Comment: Even if you can't read Japanese well, my dictionary gives "talking or acting in such a way as to make those around you draw away". WWWJDIC says "drawing away from someone because of their speech or actions; having the mood ruined". It gives an example sentence, in which ドン引き is translated as "you creeper!". Seems clear to me.

Answer (score 5):

When someone says or does something that you dislike or makes you nervous / uncomfortable, you may withdraw or keep your distance from them. This is donbiki. Rather than actually withdrawing from them, you can express the same by saying donbiki...